# Matlab - define a function that is a summation

Tags: matlab, function, symbolic-math

I am trying to define I function which I will derivate later and the function is

[image]
My code is as below:

```
syms i q j
syms f(i,q)
f=symsum(((1-q)^(i-j))*j*q,j,0,i)
```

The `f` I get shows me 4 terms but in fact I do not know this number. Is it correct or how do I enter this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please don't use `i` and `j,` because they correspond to the imaginary unit; that causes misunderstandings.

```
syms N q k
syms f(i,q)
f=symsum(((1-q)^(N-k))*k*q,k,0,N)

piecewise(q == 0, 0, q ~= 0, (q + N*q - q*(1 - q)^N + (1 - q)^N - 1)/q)
```

The result is a [piecewise](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/piecewise.html), and it says that the result is 0 if `q` is 0, and otherwise the formula given on the right.

You can also evaluate `Sum[(1 - q)^(M - k) k q, {k, 0, M}]` with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), where you get the same result. As you see, your formula can be written without the sum. You get the derivative with `D[Sum[(1 - q)^(M - k) k q, {k, 0, M}],q]` on WolframAlpha.